# spark-submit with prometheus operator

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am trying to use `spark` on `Kubernetes`. Idea is to using `spark-submit` to `k8s` cluster which is running `prometheus operator`. Now I know that `prometheus operator` can respond to `ServiceMonitor` yaml but I am confused how to provide some of the things required in the `YAML` using `spark-submit`

Here is the `YAML`:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: sparkloads-metrics
  namespace: runspark
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: runspark
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - runspark
  endpoints:
  - port: 8192 ---> How to provide the name to port using `spark-submit`
    interval: 30s
    scheme: http
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot provide additional ports and their names to the Service created by `SparkSubmit` yet (Spark v2.4.4). Things can change in the later versions.

What you can do is create additional Kubernetes `Service` (Spark Monitoring Service, eg. of type Cluster IP) per Spark job after the Job submission with `SparkSubmit`, for instance running `spark-submit ... && kubectl apply ...` . Or use any of the available Kubernetes clients with the language of your choice.

Note that you can use [Kubernetes OwnerReference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/#owners-and-dependents) to configure automatic `Service` deletion/GC on `Spark Driver Pod` deletion.

Then you can supply the `ServiceMonitor`'s via the Prometheus Operator Helm values:

```
prometheus:
  additionalServiceMonitors:
     - name: spark-metrics           # <- Spark Monitoring Service name
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: spark-metrics     # <- Spark Monitoring Service label
      namespaceSelector:
        any: true
      endpoints:
      - interval: 10s
        port: metrics                # <- Spark Monitoring Service port name
```

Be aware of the fact that Spark doesn't provide a way to customize `Spark Pod`s yet, so your Pod ports which should expose metrics are not exposed on a Pod level and won't be accessible via `Service`. To overcome it you can add additional `EXPOSE ... 8088` statement in the `Dockerfile` and rebuild Spark image.

This guide should help you to setup Spark monitoring with PULL strategy using for example [Jmx Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter).

There is an alternative (though it is recommended only for short-running Spark jobs, but you can try it in your environment if you do not run huge workloads):

- Deploy [Prometheus Pushgateway](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-pushgateway) and integrate it with your Prometheus Operator
- Configure [Spark Prometheus Sink](https://github.com/banzaicloud/spark-metrics/blob/master/PrometheusSink.md)

By doing that your Spark Pods will PUSH metrics to the Gateway and Prometheus will PULL them from the Gateway in order.

You can refer the [Spark Monitoring Helm chart](https://github.com/jahstreet/spark-on-kubernetes-helm/tree/master/charts/spark-monitoring) example with the Prometheus Operator and Prometheus Pushgateway combined.

Hope it helps.